# Java - modelandview in modelandview

Tags: spring, templates, jakarta-ee, modelandview

How can I addObject to modelandview with modelandview parameter? I mean something like that:

```
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("index");
    ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
    m.addObject("test", t, '1');
    mav.addObject("site", m);
```

I mean I have a index file witch I deal like a template and I want to parse it to other file (template)

My second question:
Is this good solution? If not, please tell me what is preffered:)

Sorry, I'm new to Java EE and Spring

edit: source code

Answer (score 0):

`ModelAndView` is just a container used by Spring's MVC request handling. Every object you add to `ModelAndView` will be added as request attribute ([`request#setAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)) and then available within your JSP.

Nesting  `ModelAndView` does not make any sense. You can just forward the request from your JSP file and all the model attributes will be still set on the request and available.

---

Regarding your approach:

I would say that having *template* JSP (such as your *index*) can be used. I personally prefer having TAG file with layout and then JSP files being enclosed within this layout.

```
<%@ tag language="java" description="Content border for layout decoration." trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pageContent">
        <jsp:doBody />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

-

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/taglib.jspf"%>
<layout:admin>
    THIS IS MY CONTENT
</layout:admin>
```

Alternatively you can use templating engine such as [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/).